# How to retrieve selective objects from a database ? Objetcs rendered redundantly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, sqlite

I'm trying to retrieve some objects in my DB but I can't figure out how.
I tried with scopes without success but I don't think it was the right solution.

Here are my main involved files (unnecessary lines removed) :

```
# app/controllers/operators_controller.rb
class OperatorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @operators = Operator.all.sort_by_newest
  end
```

With the following scope :

```
# app/models/operator.rb
  scope :sort_by_newest, -> { order('created_at DESC') }
```

Then

```
# app/views/operators/index.html.erb
<ul class="operators">
  <%= render @operators %>
</ul>
```

Which is calling the following partial :

```
# app/views/operators/_operator.html.erb
<% @operators.where(local:true).find_each do |operator| %>
  <li><%= link_to operator.name, operator %></li>
<% end %>
```

Operators has a `Local` value (boolean, `false` by default), there are 3 elements where `local` = `true` (then 36 where local = false).

```
2.2.0 :003 > Operator.all.count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "operators"
 => 39
2.2.0 :004 > Operator.where(local: true).count
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "operators" WHERE "operators"."local" = 't'
 => 3
2.2.0 :005 > Operator.where(local: false).count
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "operators" WHERE "operators"."local" = 'f'
 => 36
```

The problem is: it renders me the 3 local=true elements... 39 times !

[image: The 3 single objects I need are orange. Rendered 39 times.]

*The 3 single objects I need are orange. Rendered 39 times.*

How to make this work?

EDIT :

I'd like to have many renders in many pages (one with the "local:true" elements, another with the "global:true" elements, etc.) So I guess I cannot modify directly into the operators:index method ?

Comment: Try changing this `@operators = Operator.all.sort_by_newest` to `@operators = Operator.where(local: true).sort_by_newest`

Comment: When doing it, it renders me 9 results : 3 times the 3 objects I need (just as the @MurifoX answer).

Comment: I need to add : I'd like to have many renders in many pages (one with the "local:true" elements, another with "global:true" elements, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing duplicated work. Try searching for the operators in your controller action with the specific query:

```
def index
  @operators = Operator.where(local: true).sort_by_newest
end
```

Then just print the `operator` attributes, without the iterator inside your partial:

```
<li><%= link_to operator.name, operator %></li>
```

Comment: Hi Murifo, thanks for your answer. I've just tried this : Now it renders me 9 results, 3 times the 3 objects I need...

Comment: Well, it has to do with how Rails handles partial internally. (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) You don't need to iterate through the `operators`. Remove the iterator and i believe it will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `<%= render @operators %>`, it will render `_operator.html.erb` partial. But you do not need to iterate through `@operators` object to render each individual `@operators` object. Just write the code assuming you are in the `each` block:

```
<li><%= link_to operator.name, operator %></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

To comment on my own for the problem I asked after Editing the OP (how to make a request without touching operator:index method)

You can have multiples views of the DB without touching the operator:index method :

```
# app/model/operator.rb
def index
  @operators = Operator.all.sort_by_newest
end
```

And the renders that takes the requests (as said before, that actually iterates so don't need to iterate into the partials, otherwise you'll have duplicates) :

```
<%= render @operators #%>
<%= render @operators.where(local:true) %>
<%= render @operators.where(global:true) %>
```